# SQL query does not executes because of escaped characters

Tags: java, sql, xml, sql-server-2016

let's say i have sql query like this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE columnid <= 5
```

defined in orm.xml like this:

```
<named-query>
  <query>
    sql query
  </query>
</named-query>
```

Environment said that the xml is not well formed, because of < character. So then i googled for explanation and i found, that i have to escape characters as in the following example

```
< = &lt , > = &gt
```

But when i excaped these characters, the query doesn't execute. It's not valid, because of the escaping. Do you please have any idea how to fix this or any workaround?

Comment: how are you picking up query from xml? you need to HTTP decode it back to < from &lt;. Something like here. See the sample in the link and click decode. https://codebeautify.org/html-decode-string

Comment: `&gt;` with semicolon. Using normal XML API functions setting and getting would hide this.

Comment: well, i dont exactly know how i am picking up queries, cause this orm.xml file is not mapped anywhere...im working with spring and hibernate so it has  to do that itself somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is still open, but - at least - it is unanswered:

You should not think of XML as a string with fancy extra characters. Putting content *into* the XML has some rules and reading values *from within* XML has some rules too. You can easily create something which *looks* like XML on string level, but - if your xml ist not valid - you'll get into troubles.

The most important exceptions are - obviously! - `<, > and &`, which would disturb the markup, if not escaped.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<root>SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE columnid &lt;= 5</root>';
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/root/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

You'll find, that the escaped character is re-converted implicitly. **But you must read the XML with an appropriate tool!**. If you read the XML with string methods (like `substring`), you'll have to ensure the re-escaping yourself.

There is a - not recommended - workaround: You can use a `CDATA`-section like here:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<root><![CDATA[SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE columnid <= 5]]></root>';
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/root/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

This allows you to place text into the XML which will be take *as-is*. But this is outdated and not supported directly in SQL-Server (Well, there is `FOR XML EXPLICIT`, which is outdated by itself). SQL-Server will actually store the above without `CDATA` as escaped string automatically. Semantically  it's the same...